# Implement Ordered trait with covariant generic

Tags: scala, generics, covariance

Is there a way mix in the Ordered trait for a covariant generic?

I have the following code:

```
trait Foo[+T  <: Foo[T]] extends Ordered[T] {

  def id: Int

  override def compare(that : T) : Int = {
    this.id compare that.id
  }    
}
```

Where I need `T` covariant and would like ordered to work too. The version above gives the "covariant type in contravariant position error".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `Ordered` with a  covariant type because it requires the generic type in a contravariant position.  Instead, you should use an implicit `Ordering`defined in the companion object

```
trait Foo[+T] {
  def id: Int

}

object Foo {
  implicit def fooOrdering[A <: Foo[_]]: Ordering[A] = {
    new Ordering[A] {
      override def compare(x: A, y: A): Int = x.id compare y.id
    }
  }
}
```

Any reasonable function that compares object should be take in an Ordering instance for the objects it is comparing, and many do implicitly.  For example

```
case class F(id: Int) extends Foo[Int]
case class G(id: Int) extends Foo[Int]

List(F(1), F(2), F(5), F(3), G(12)).max // = G(12)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ordered[A]` is invariant in `A`. [The old documentation for this trait explains why](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/Ordered.html):

> A trait for totally ordered data. Note that since version 2006-07-24 this trait is no longer covariant in a. It is important that the equals method for an instance of Ordered[A] be consistent with the compare method. However, due to limitations inherent in the type erasure semantics, there is no reasonable way to provide a default implementation of equality for instances of Ordered[A]. Therefore, if you need to be able to use equality on an instance of Ordered[A] you must provide it yourself either when inheiriting or instantiating. It is important that the hashCode method for an instance of Ordered[A] be consistent with the compare method. However, it is not possible to provide a sensible default implementation. Therefore, if you need to be able compute the hash of an instance of Ordered[A] you must provide it yourself either when inheiriting or instantiating.

This means if you want to use `Ordered[A]` you'll explicitly have to provide an implementation of `compare` for subtypes of `Foo`.

A workaround can be done with an implicit `Ordering[A]`:

```
implicit def ord[A <: Foo[A]] = new math.Ordering[A] {
  override def compare(a: A, b: A) = a.id compare b.id
}
```